# i want keep same datatable row reorder even after page reload

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

*Please help me, I am just stucked in datatable row reorder extension.
Datatable is working fine, reordering is working fine but i want that reordering don't lost after page reload.
My Table data is coming from database.
*

Here it is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin Page </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        rowReorder: true,
        update: false
    } );  


    table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
        var result = 'Reorder started on row: '+edit.triggerRow.data()[1]+'<br>';

        for ( var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            var rowData = table.row( diff[i].node ).data();

            result += rowData[1]+' updated to be in position '+
                diff[i].newData+' (was '+diff[i].oldData+')<br>';
        }

        $('#result').html( 'Event result:<br>'+result );

    } );
} );
   </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Manage registered user</h2>

  <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_id">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $news_item['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $news_item['fname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $news_item['lname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $news_item['email']; ?></td>
        <td>

                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_ctrl/admin_crud_edit_ctrl/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">Edit</a> | 
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_ctrl/admin_crud_del_ctrl/'.$news_item['id']);?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a> |
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_ctrl/change_user_ctrl/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">Make Him Admin</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to store the order in your database, or in a session/cookie if you want it per-user.

You copy-pasted the 'row-reorder' function from the official Example, modify that so it save the order of each of your rows somewhere. Then use these values when initializing your Datatable.

Everything you need should be in these two links:

https://www.datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/defaults.html

https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html

I do not think there is a way to make this process automatic, but I often found that Datatables had some magical features so I might be wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

View:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var qqq = $( "tbody" );
 qqq.sortable({     
     axis: "y",   
    update: function (event, ui) {      
        var data = qqq.sortable('serialize');       
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save_order_fun',
            success: function(response) {
              #do what you want todo
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Controller:-

```
function save_order_fun()
   {
      $this->admin_model->save_order_model();   
   }
```

Model:-

```
   function save_order_model()
   {
      $i = 0;
      $orderlist = $_POST['serialize'];
      foreach ($orderlist as $k) {
      
      $this->db->SET('position',$i);
      $this->db->WHERE('id',$k);
      $this->db->UPDATE('user');

      $i++;
      }
   }
```